# CMS config - MySQL or XML?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, content-management-system, config

My CMS will have a number of config values such as site name, slogan and so on - which will be read every time a page is generated. These values will of course be cached with a duration set to 1-2 hours or similar (which will get reseted on settings-change).

Should I save these values using XML or MySQL? What's the best way to do this, performance vise?

Comment: What about the other options such as INI files or JSON? Besides that, you cannot even store your MySQL data in the MySQL database as your application wouldn't be able to access them without connecting to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call it traditional, but i find `.INI` files to be particularly useful with PHP apps.

PHP has a built-in [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function that makes this a breeze

Conveniently, it returns an array which you can use to merge multiple files into a single `$config` array or `AppConfig` singleton class

In fact, PHP uses an .INI file to configure itself!  See `/etc/php.ini` :)

---

You can do useful things like

#### config/db.ini

```
[development]
host = localhost
user = foo
pass = password123
name = dev_db

[production]
host = localhost
user = sqluser
pass = AJ539jf
name = live_db
```

When passing `true` to the second argument in `parse_ini_file()`, PHP will use section titles as array keys.  The output will look something like this

```
Array
(
    [db] => Array
        (
            [development] => Array
                (
                    [host] => localhost
                    [user] => foo
                    [pass] => password123
                    [name] => dev_db
                )

            [production] => Array
                (
                    [host] => localhost
                    [user] => sqluser
                    [pass] => AJ539jf
                    [name] => live_db
                )

        )

)
```

This is great because you can check all of your configuration files into version control and simply use a one-line app configuration file or environment variable that determines which env your app is running in

---

Another answer suggest adhering to the configuration guidelines of the CMS you chose, however, I find most PHP frameworks miss the mark in this area; especially when it comes to supporting multiple configurations for different environments.  Writing your own "extension" that handles app configuration properly is usually one of the first things we'll do to circumvent a particular CMS's rigid solution.

An added benefit to using a big configuration array is it's easily encodable to JSON if you want to have other apps or services interact with your app.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the CMS in general, and stick to whatever is being used as the convention there.  Nothing worse than looking for config/settings that all appear somewhere, only to find the one that YOU'RE looking for is an anomaly that is hidden somewhere else.  The performance in this case is minimal with any choice.

Answer (score 0):

For me, XML is the better way to store configurations.
It's easy to read and write (by all the language), and easy to control by someone other than the geeks and easy to control by version control (SVN, Git).